# How can I run model validations before the setterMethod in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sequelize.js

I want to save a hashed password. I'm using a setterMethod for this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) ->
  sequelize.define 'User',
    # other model fields [...]
    password:
      type: DataTypes.STRING
      validate: notEmpty: msg: 'You need to set a password.'
      set: (pw) ->
        salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        hash = bcrypt.hashSync(pw, salt)
        @setDataValue('password', hash)
```

The setter runs first. An empty string password (`''`) is hashed into a non-empty one (say `$2a$10$pDDIGnV.r47i9YOv0Fls/euQ0yYvfyq8T1SyP9VRQsTUAqptNmxXO`).

When the validator validates, the password is not empty anymore.

**How can I validate the password before the setter?**

I looked into [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/) but they don't mention setters either.

I'm using `sequelize@2.1.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using two fields, one being type `VIRTUAL` that handles the input and validation, and one being type `STRING` that holds the hashed password.

This example is not `coffeescript` but you should be able to translate easily.

```js
password_hash: {
  type: DatabaseTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    notEmpty: true,
  },
},
password: {
  type: DatabaseTypes.VIRTUAL,
  allowNull: false,
  // note that arrow functions cannot access "this", so use the form:
  set: function setPassword(val) {
    // trigger validation on "password" field
    this.setDataValue('password', val);

    // hash the password, this can be done in one step by passing the
    // number of salt rounds instead of the salt string.
    this.setDataValue('password_hash', bcrypt.hashSync(val, 10));
  },
  validate: {
    notEmpty: {
       message: 'You need to set a password.',
    },
  },
},
```

When you authenticate the user compare the entered password to `User.password_hash` rather than `User.password`.

```js
instanceMethods: {
  // authenticate user given a password
  authenticate(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password_hash);
  },
},
```

You can then call this instance method to authenticate a `User`.

```js
User.findById(userId)
.then((user) => {
  if (user.authenticate(password)) {
    console.log('Authenticated');
  } else {
    console.log('Not authenticated');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the beforeCreate hook as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120548/using-bcrypt-with-sequelize-model)

Essentially, your model code would look something like this

```js
User.init(
  {
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: {
          args: [6],
          msg: "Minimum password length is 6 characters",
        },
        notEmpty: {
          args: [true],
          msg: "Please enter a password",
        },
        notNull: {
          args: [true],
          msg: "Please enter a password",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: async (user) =>
        (user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)),
    },
    sequelize,
    modelName: "User",
  },
);
```

Check the Sequelize hooks API reference [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html)

Answer (score 0):

So I used the beforeSave hook, for both insert and update. I tested it out seems to do the trick - validations work as intended as well.

```js
User.init(
  {
    // attributes
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          msg: "Email address is entered is invalid",
        },
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          msg: "Password cannot be empty",
        },
        notNull: {
          msg: "Password cannot be null",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeSave: (user, options) => {
        if (options.fields.includes("password")) {
          user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10)
        }
      },
    },
    sequelize,
    modelName: "user",
    underscored: true,
  }
)
```