# Cannot register with password encrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120548/using-bcrypt-with-sequelize-model) but i still didn't figure out how to solve it, it says to use instanceMethods option to use the methods in the model thats exactly what i did:

```
"use strict";
var sequelize = require('./index');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
      instanceMethods: {
        generateHash: function (password) {
          console.log("hi");
          return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
        validPassword: function (password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
      },


    });



  return User;
}
```

after i use that i tried to test it generating a password hash on my register route like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../../models').User;
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

  if (JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}") {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Register request body is empty" });
  }
  if (!req.body.email || !req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Missing fields for registration" });
  }



  var password = User.instaceMethods.generateHash(req.body.password);

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: password
  }).then(function () {
    return res.status(200).json({message: "user created"});
  })

});

module.exports = router;
```

with this when i go to my /register, i don't get any response even a console.log in the password doesn't show me anything i tried to see if it enters the generetehash but, it doesn't enter the method, what is going wrong here?

Comment: i did, not working either :(, i don't get any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `generateHash` as a classMethod of your model, not an instance method.

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  ....
}, {
  classMethods: {
    generateHash: function() {
      ...
    }
})
```

Because you don't have an instance yet, not before `User.create()`.

Then you can call it using `User.generateHash()`

And also you should catch (and probably at least log) sequelize exceptions. Add

```
.catch(function(err){
  console.log(err)
})
```

after your `then()`

Comment: can i ask you something else really fast?

Comment: thnx. another question? not sure if a i can help, not really soo experienced with sequelize and node myself

Comment: well tnks anyway, maybe i ask another here on stackoverflow :D